# Unable to run addfinalizer function within a fixture with scope as class

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Here’s my test code:

```python
import string
import pytest
import tempfile
import os

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def TempFile(request):
    (tmp_cfg_fd, tmp_cfg_file_path) = tempfile.mkstemp()
    os.close(tmp_cfg_fd)
    def RemoveTempFile():
        print("Removing %r" %(tmp_cfg_file_path))
        os.remove(tmp_cfg_file_path)
    request.addfinalizer(RemoveTempFile)
    return tmp_cfg_file_path

@pytest.mark.usefixtures(TempFile)
class Test:
    def test1(self):
        print("I'm in test1")

    def test2(self):
        print("I'm in test2")
```

When I run `py.test` on it, I get this error:

```
test_4.py:17: in <module>
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures(TempFile)
test_4.py:14: in TempFile
    request.addfinalizer(RemoveTempFile)
E   AttributeError: class Test has no attribute 'addfinalizer'
```

When the fixture has `scope='class'`, then the `Test` class fails to run `addfinalizer`.

But if the fixture has `scope='function'`, and I call the `TempFile` fixture individually in `test1` and `test2` functions, then `addfinalizer` runs properly.

How can I get `addfinalizer` to run with `scope='class'`?

Answer (score 4):

The usefixtures mark takes an string, if you change the mark into:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('TempFile')
```

it will work correctly.